# How to add prev/next buttons to a jQuery image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a image gallery with jQuery found here:

http://sarfraznawaz2005.kodingen.com/demos/jquery/image_gallery/

I just wanted to know how to I add functionality to prev and next arrow images to show next and previous images with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to find an element before/after the current one and activate it. You will need to decouple element activation code from the onclick event.

you're using

```
 $(...).click(function() {
     code
     that 
     activates
     "this"
 });
```

but now you need to reuse the activation code, so decouple it

```
 activate = function(elem) {
     code
     that 
     activates
     "elem"
 }

 $(img).click(function() {
     activate(this)
 });

 $(#left).click(function() {
     activate(currentElement.prev())
 });

 $(#right).click(function() {
     activate(currentElement.next())
 });
```

Comment: +1: thanks i am alredy using that but having some problems. Ok what do you mean by decouple element activation code?